# Is this normal that pin 1 & 2 are shorted with HT1628 led display driver?

Tags: circuit-design, led-driver, short-circuit, 7segmentdisplay

I just received from China, components to build my own induction cooker (yeah, I know it's strange but I want to add my own features on it ;-) ) and I'm a little disappointed with the build quality of the controller board. However, what surprised me the most, is that on the display driver for the control panel, pins 1 and 2 of the ht1628 led display driver are shorted. Can someone tell me if this can be “by design” (is there a valid reason to do this with this chip) or if it's included in the low build quality (i.e. Is this a bug or a feature ? ;-) )

EDIT : Since I needed to have a proof it doesn't work, I faced my fears of breaking it beyond repair and tested it, as is... And it appears it works. I don't understand how...

[image: HT1628 pins shorted]

Comment: Pin 1 is an oscillator configuration pin (resistance to ground); pin 2 is a serial I/O pin. I really don't think they're meant to be connected.

Comment: I also don't think so, but I want to make sure before I act ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I *think* it's a mistake. Pin 1 is an oscillator configuration pin (a resistor to ground); pin 2 is a data input/output to the microcontroller. Completely different. They're not both power pins for example.

Also you can see that traces are separated on the circuit board.

Comment: Well... Since I needed to have a proof it doesn't work, I faced my fears of breaking it beyond repair and tested it, as is... And it appears it works. I don't understand how...